# InstantiationException when initializing a class extending FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-view

I created a class extending FrameLayout:

```
public class EnhancedMapView extends FrameLayout
{
private CustomMapView mapViewComponent;

public EnhancedMapView(Context context,String apiKey)
{
    super(context);
    /*mapViewComponent=new CustomMapView(context,apiKey);
    catch (Exception exception) 
    { 
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements=exception.getStackTrace();
        for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement:stackTraceElements)
            Log.i("Blabla",stackTraceElement.toString());
    }
    buildMapViewLayout();*/
}
}
```

And this is the activity I'm using the class in:

```
public class TestMapViewActivity extends Activity 
{
private EnhancedMapView enhancedMapView;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String apiKey=getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_api_key);
    enhancedMapView=new EnhancedMapView(this,apiKey);
    setContentView(enhancedMapView);
}
}
```

And I'm getting:

```
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{shira.android.mapview/shira.android.mapview.EnhancedMapView}: java.lang.InstantiationException: shira.android.mapview.EnhancedMapView
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: shira.android.mapview.EnhancedMapView
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-23 11:43:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
```

Originally, I had some code using Google Maps, but I commented out all of it. It seems the exception comes from the FrameLayout constructor, which I'm calling from my custom view class (using super), and I have no idea what makes it happen...

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Because it's a simple layout (at least for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, it was a stupid mistake I made. I put in the activity declaration in the manifest the name of the view instead of the activity. My apologizes to anyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the default constructors:

```
public EnhancedMapView(Context context){
     this(context, null);
}

public EnhancedMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
     this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public EnhancedMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
     super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

Comment: I already added the last 2. I'll try the first one, but I don't want applications using this view to be able to call a constructor that doesn't get a Google Maps API key as an argument.